# Ceiling fan does not turn off. Stuck in high. No wall switch no remote. Light does not work

Tags: electrical, wiring

Ceiling fan will not turn off.  Runs on high.  No wall switch.  No remote.  Light does not work. Oklahoma usa

Comment: Turn off the breaker, find the remote, replace light bulb.

Comment: Can you turn the breaker off and post photos of the fan's wiring please?

Comment: The remote control inside the fan is broken, or the dog eat the remote.

Comment: Does it have pull chain switches?

Answer (score 1):

It is uncommon to have a Fan/Light without wall switch, but since you had a remote it is possible.

Since the remote is lost,

Turn off the appropriate circuit beaker.

Open the fan and remove the remote controller.

If you can find the replacement for the original (with remote) do so,

if not get one of those universal fan remotes.